# I am having the string , i have to convert it into hash like no 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my code:

```
 1. "special_filter,|filter_str,(&(a=1)(c=11)(p=c=11,o=m,d=4))"


 2.{ "a" =>"1", "c" => "11" , "p" => "c=11,o=m,d=4"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

string = "special_filter,|filter_str,(&(a=1)(c=11)(p=c=11,o=m,d=4))"
hash = {}
string.slice(/\(&.*\)/).split(")").each do |match|
  match.tr("(&","").split("=",2).each_slice(2) { |key, value| hash[key] = value }
end
```

### Line by line:

**Line 1:** Set a variable, string, with the starting string.

`string = "special_filter,|filter_str,(&(a=1)(c=11)(p=c=11,o=m,d=4))"`

**Line 2:** Set a variable, hash, with an empty hash to fill.

`hash = {}`

**Line 3:**

- Cut out the portion of the string that matches this regexp

`string.slice(/\(&.*\)/) => "(&(a=1)(c=11)(p=c=11,o=m,d=4))"`

> The regexp is bookended with forward slashes (/regexp goes here/). 
>   Parentheses have special meaning in regex, so they must be escaped with backslashes. 
>   The & matches the & in the string. 
>   In regex, a . means any character. 
>   * means none to unlimited of the preceding character.
>   So this regex matches (&) as well as (&fjalsdkfj).

- Split the string by right parentheses

`string.slice(/\(&.*\)/).split(")") => ["(&(a=1", "(c=11", "(p=c=11,o=m,d=4"]`

- Then iterate through the array of results

`string.slice(/\(&.*\)/).split(")").each do |match|`

**Line 4:**

- Take the iteration and remove unwanted characters from it

`match.tr("(&","")`

- Split it one time, using the first `=` sign

`match.tr("(&","").split("=",2)`

- Use the 2 value array as a key and value on the hash

`match.tr("(&","").split("=",2).each_slice(2) { |key, value| hash[key] = value }`

Comment: thanks, one more thing is the string will be vary according to condition if my string is "a =1" or "c=c=1,o=m,d=4" then how could i convert it to hash.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: my string will be (a=1) or (c=c=1,o=m,d=4) how could i convert this to hash like {"a"=>"1"} and {"c"=>"c=1,o=m,d=4"}

Comment: I just wrote you a book explaining how to do that. Look at the last line and adapt it. `string.tr("()","").split("=",2).each_slice(2) { |x, y| hash[x] = y }`

Answer (score 1):

My try to this.

```
Hash[*string[/\&.*/].tr("&(","").split(")").map{|i| i.split("=",2)}.flatten]
```

Some ideas taken from @Conner's solution ;)

Thanks @corner I was able to know some functions i never used before.